# Passing Native Function a reference variable in Java JNA

Tags: java, jna

I am trying to write a Java applet to connect to a bar-code scanner and read the data.  The bar-code scanner comes with a dll file with functions to access it.  I don't have a lot of experience with Java but I've figured out how to use JNA to load the dll and call the native functions. Some of the functions work fine but the one that returns the actual bar-codes I can't seem to get to work.  It takes a character array as an argument and pass by reference is not in JNA, I've tried using the Pointer class and can't get anything to work. The native functions definition is as follows.

NoMangle long DLL_IMPORT_EXPORT csp2GetPacket ( char szBarData[],long nBarcodeNumber,long nMaxLength )

After the function call the szBarData[] variable is supposed to contain the bar-code data.

I've tried setting up the JNA map several different ways, making the szBarData[] argument a char array, string, a byte array, and a pointer, and have had no luck.

in visual basic you can pass the szBarData[] a string and it works, just not sure how to accomplish this in Java using JNA.

Comment: Try passing a "char[]" in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're expecting the target function to fill in your buffer, you *cannot* pass a `String` (which is read-only) but must instead pass a `byte[]`.

Also make sure you're not using Java `long` to represent native `long`; the class `NativeLong` exists for that purpose.

If what you get back is a NUL-terminated C string, then you can use `Native.toString(byte[])` to convert to a `String`.

Comment: This worked, I tried using a byte[] based on another forum I saw, but I kept getting random stuff returned.  And I tried using a couple different toString() functions along with it but the same results, I never came across the Native.toString() in any other forums or documentation, but it works perfect.  Thank you very much!!

Comment: Feel free to contribute a documentation patch!